# Ubuntu 22.04 HDMI option on sound output has disappeared along with alsamixer

Tags: 22.04, alsa, hdmi, output

It started when I connected my 2nd HDMI monitor a few days ago. I use 1 HDMI full time for TV monitor and sound and a second HDMI port for projector. After enjoying a movie on the projector my option to output sound back to my HDMI monitor disappeared from the list of selectable devices. Now only the headphone built in audio is available. Also alsamixer disappeared as well. When typing `alsamixer` in terminal the result does not pull up the mixer like it always has. Now it reads back:

```
ALSA lib confmisc.c:855parse_card) cannot find card '0'
ALSA lib conf.c:5178_snd_config_evaluate) function snd_func_card_inum returned error: No such file or directory
ALSA lib confmisc.c:422snd_func_concat) error evaluating strings
ALSA lib conf.c:5178_snd_config_evaluate) function snd_func_concat returned error: No such file or directory
ALSA lib confmisc.c:1334snd_func_refer) error evaluating name
ALSA lib conf.c:5178_snd_config_evaluate) function snd_func_refer returned error: No such file or directory
ALSA lib conf.c:5701snd_config_expand) Evaluate error: No such file or directory
ALSA lib control.c:1528snd_ctl_open_noupdate) Invalid CTL default
cannot open mixer: No such file or directory
```

I also got the "no AFG or MFG" message when booting.
Even though I have 2 HDMI ports, when typing `aplay -l` into terminal I get:

```
**** List of PLAYBACK Hardware Devices ****
card 1: Generic [HD-Audio Generic], device 0: ALC221 Analog [ALC221 Analog]
Subdevices: 0/1
Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
```

All trouble shooting - rebooting, disconnecting HDMI, rebooting, reconnecting HDMI, rebooting, connecting to different port, rebooting - no results. Yes, `alsamixer` is in computer`/usr/bin/alsamixer`. Yes `sudo ubuntu-drivers autoinstall` command results in:

All the available drivers are already installed.

Somehow connecting the 2nd HDMI causes all HDMI (spdf) to get "blocked?" Reinstalling fresh Ubuntu worked in bringing HDMI audio output back but then I plugged by 2nd HDMI back in to watch a movie again today. POOF! Alsamixer cannot find card 0. HDMI sound output option disappeared.

Comment: This may be related to this bug that has affected recent kernel upgrades: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/2009136

Comment: Try to upgrade kernel. It worked fine for me. https://github.com/pimlie/ubuntu-mainline-kernel.sh

Comment: @user1683903 Thank you! I've been messing with drivers for 10 hours trying to get sound back. I followed your link and decided to try updating to the latest kernel and sound is back. Thank you so much!